# Angular CanLoad guard triggers only once upon first lazy load?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm encountering a strange behaviour (or maybe a wanted one). I have an Angular application where all the modules are lazy loaded.

On one module I have a guard that checks if the decoded user from the JWT is a *system admin*. If so, the user shall proceed to the section, otherwise it will be redirected in dashboard.

The strange thing is that this thing works **only** upon the **first** module load. Then, if I try to logout and access with a user that is **not** as system admin, the CanLoad guard does not trigger.

I've also tried to implement in the same guard the (CanActivate and CanActivateChild) interfaces, and put the guard on the `app-routing.module.ts` and on the `feature-routing.module.ts` modules, respectively on the *CanLoad*, *CanActivate*, and *CanActivateChild* properties of the modules.

The *CanActivate* *CanActivateChild* methods **never** gets called. **Never**.

While the *CanLoad* placed on the `app-routing.module.ts` is called just once.

#### Here's the `is-sys-adm.guard.ts` file:

```
export class SFWIsSysAdmGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

        public constructor(
            private readonly accessSvc: SFWAuthService,
            private readonly toastSvc: NbToastrService,
            private readonly translateSvc: TranslateService,
            private readonly navigationSvc: NavigationService,
        ) { }


        public canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
            console.log('Can activate child hit');
            return this.canLoad(undefined, undefined);
        }

        public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
            console.log('Can activate hit');
            return this.canLoad(undefined, undefined);
        }

        public canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): boolean {
            console.log('Can load hit');
            const decodedUser = this.accessSvc.decodedUser;
            if (!!decodedUser && !!decodedUser.isSystemAdmin) {
                return true;
            }

            this.navigationSvc.goToDashboard();
            this.toastSvc.warning(
                this.translateSvc.instant('framework.guards.adm_only.access_denied'),
                this.translateSvc.instant('common.access_to_section_denied_ttl'),
            );
            return false;
        }
    }
```

#### Here's the `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: `/${AppRoutes.access}`,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.dashboard,
            loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.DashboardModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.pins,
            loadChildren: () => import('./pins/pins.module').then(mod => mod.PinsModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.pinTypes,
            loadChildren: () => import('./pin-types/pin-types.module').then(mod => mod.PinTypesModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.organizationPickup,
            loadChildren: () => import('./organization-picker/organization-picker.module').then(mod => mod.OrganizationPickerModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.access,
            loadChildren: () => import('./access/access.module').then(mod => mod.AccessModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.tourism,
            loadChildren: () => import('./tourism/tourism.module').then(mod => mod.TourismModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.security,
            canLoad: [SFWIsSysAdmGuard],
            loadChildren: () => import('./security/security.module').then(mod => mod.SecurityModule)
        },
        {
            path: AppRoutes.notFound,
            loadChildren: () => import('./not-found/not-found.module').then(mod => mod.NotFoundModule)
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            redirectTo: '/404'
        }
    ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

#### Last but not least: `feature-routing.module.ts` file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [SFWIsSysAdmGuard],
        component: SecurityComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tokens-generator',
                canActivateChild: [SFWIsSysAdmGuard],
                component: TokensGeneratorComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SecurityRoutingModule { }


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SecurityRoutingModule { }
```

Before you ask, I've also tried to put the guard separately in a *CanActivate*, *CanActivateChild*, *CanLoad* to try to prevent any conflict (which shouldn't exist if I've understand the docs.)

Am I missing something? Is is a wanted behaviour or should I open a bug on the official repo?

Thank to anyone willing to spend time on this <3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `CanLoad` determines whether the lazy module can be loaded from the server. After it has been loaded, this will not be checked again (unless you press F5). I guess you need to declare it twice, once in `CanLoad` (if you don't want the code to be loaded at all), and `CanActivate`, if you want to restrict access.

```
{
  path: AppRoutes.security,
  canLoad: [SFWIsSysAdmGuard],
  canActivate: [SFWIsSysAdmGuard],
  loadChildren: () => import('./security/security.module').then(mod => mod.SecurityModule)
},
```

Comment: hey! Thank you so much! As I thought, I was doing something wrong, and what you explained makes a lot of sense! Tried and it works, thanks, I've learned something new :)